# Usos do “porquê” no português europeu?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, português-europeu

Caros colegas, apesar do que considero um bom domínio da gramática do português brasileiro, sempre tive dificuldades em entender o uso dos porquês no português europeu. No Brasil, usamos basicamente esses *porquês*, a saber:

- Por que você vai embora? (interrogativo, com preposição e pronome relativo);
- Porque já é tarde. (causal, com a conjunção *porque*);
- Não sei por que você saiu. (preposição e pronome, no sentido de *a razão pela qual*);
- Você saiu por quê? (o *que* é acentuado, pois se torna tônico no fim da oração);
- Por quê, mais uma vez, você gritou? (alguns gramáticos defendem o acento nesse *que*, por este se tornar tônico por causa da pausa forçada pela vírgula);
- Porque você estava doente? (esse é o uso menos popular no Brasil, ou seja, é o caso em que uma resposta, referente a uma causa, é transformada em pergunta).

Como seriam grafados esses *porquês* no português europeu?

Grato pela atenção.